# Checking input only contains letters/spaces- returning a TypeError

Tags: python

I'm trying to create an encryption program, and I'm stuck at the first hurdle. I basically want to check that the input only contains letters or spaces, and if not, to return an error message.
When I run this, it says TypeError, 'bool' object is not iterable. Not sure what that means, or how to correct my code. I'm in Python 3.5.

```
sentence = input("Enter a short sentence: ").lower()

for x in sentence:
    if all(x.isalpha() or x==''):
        continue
    else:
        print("Error: please only enter letters and spaces. ")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be what you're looking for:

```
sentence = input("Enter a short sentence: ").lower()

for x in sentence:
    if x.isalpha() or x==' ':
        continue
    else:
        print("Error: please only enter letters and spaces. ")
        break
```

You were trying to perform `all() on a boolean condition (if x is alpha or empty).

Answer (score 0):

The `all` built-in checks every element of an iterable to see if it's `True`. In your case you've passed it a single boolean value `(x.isalpha() or x==' ')`. You need to give `all` an iterable to work with. You could do this with a list comprehension, for example:

```
sentence = input("Enter a short sentence: ").lower()
result = all([x.isalpha() or x == ' ' for x in sentence])
```

You can then use the value in `result` to make decisions about what to do next

Answer (score 0):

You are not using `all` correctly. The function takes some *iterable* like a list or tuple, not a single boolean, which is what you are providing it.

```
>>> all([True, True, False])
False
>>> all([True, True, True])
True
```

So, you could do something like:

```
>>> sentence1 = 'the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog'
>>> sentence2 = 'the quck brown fox jumped!1 over the lazy! dog!!!'
>>> all(c.isalpha() or c.isspace() for c in sentence1)
True
>>> all(c.isalpha() or c.isspace() for c in sentence2)
False
>>>
```